# How to produce a stream of guesses for the root of f?

Tags: scheme

I would like to produce a stream of guesses for the root of f with 3 arguments f fx and x with f = sin(x) and x = 3. I tried some code but i don't get it. I would appreciate it if you could provide me some help.

```
(define (stream f fx x)
(let ((x (3))
((f x) (sin x))
((fx x) (cos x)))
(cons-stream (x (stream f fx (x (- x (/ (f x) (fx x)))))))))

(stream f fx 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is this (I've applied indentation to make the bracketing clearer):

```
(define (stream f fx x)
  (let ((x (3))
        ((f x) (sin x))
        ((fx x) (cos x)))
    (cons-stream (x (stream f fx (x (- x (/ (f x) (fx x))))
                            ))
                 )))

(stream f fx 3)
```

You have a few mistakes in this:

- `(3)` treats 3 as a procedure and tries to call it. You should have `3` instead.
- You have put specific arguments 3, sin, cos inside the general function. It should be outside instead.
- You have done `(x (stream ...))` and `(x (- x ..))` both treat x like a function, but it's a number.

So clearing up these mistakes the code will be more like this:

```
(define (stream f fx x)
    (cons-stream x (stream f fx (- x (/ (f x) (fx x))))))

(let ((x 3)
      (f (lambda (x) (sin x)))
      (fx (lambda (x) (cos x))))
  (stream f fx x))
```

lambda was used to define a local function. Hope that helps, Feel free to ask follow up questions if anything was unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can i display my solution, say e.x. the first 8?

Comment: use `stream-take`,